# difference between gym weights and home weights

Tags: gym, home-exercise, bench-press

at home I have a york fitness bar and york weight plates...the bar is 5kg I believe...I stack 4x10kg plates and 2x5kg plates on there for a total of 50kg.
Now at the gym the bar is 20kg, but it is quite long and thicker. When I add just two 5kg plates, it feels heavier than the ones I have at home, why is this? surely the fact that it is thicker requiring stronger grip doesn't make that much of a difference, if I add 2 10kg plates, it gets really hard, yet at home it is easy...why is it like that?

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain about the unloaded bar weights for your home and your gym? Look up the specs on your bar and the bar at the gym. Grip also makes a difference, but should not be that profound.

It doesn't look like York puts up specs on most of their bars (which is bad practice IMO) but you can probably send them an e-mail. Don't know what brand or model the gym bar is, but 20kg is pretty standard. Are you sure the plates at home are weighted properly? That's a pretty strange phenomenon. 55 kg should definitely feel heavier than 40 kg.

Comment: 15kg bar for female competitions is also a widespread standard, they're probably have this one. It looks very much like 20kg one, it is really hard to tell one from another without seeing them side to side.

Comment: While it's true 15 kg bars are common, this wouldn't account for the gym weights feeling _heavier_ than expected. A lighter bar would make it feel like less effort.

Comment: @Lipophage, you are right, I don't use my home ones aynmore, I scrapped them, but the bar was 10kg, plus it was thinner than a standard olympic bar, both contribute to the difficulty factor. I also recently got a strongman bar and they let me keep it at the gym, it weighs 20kg but it is 2.8 inches thick, but it makes things feel so much harder than on an olympic bar, I must say I am having a lot of fun with it!! I love using it.